# Create a JSON object to post in Spring Boot tests

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

I want to write basic test to execute a POST request on a /users URL with JSON payload to create a user. I cannot find how to convert a new object to JSON, and so far have this much, it's obviously wrong but explains the purpose:

```
@Test public void createUser() throws Exception {
    String userJson = new User("My new User", "myemail@gmail.com").toJson();
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/users/").contentType(userJson)).andExpect(status().isCreated());
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use jackson object mapper and then user writeValueAsString method.

So

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

// or ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); this with Spring Boot is useless


    @Test public void createUser() throws Exception {
        User user = new User("My new User", "myemail@gmail.com");
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/users/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user)))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Just what I was looking for :O)

Comment: can you take a look at my post with your insight? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312481/spring-mvc-test-throwing-415-httpmediatypenotsupportedexception/63324411?noredirect=1#comment111984433_63324411

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion i m very confused for your question have you solved? it is not so clear for me any way I asked something in the comment to your question

Comment: If the IDE does not immediately offer the right import add this line `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` since the ObjectMapper from _fasterxml_ is the right one (there's currently another from _restassured_ but it's not the same)