# Spring MVC test throwing 415 HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

this may or may not be a somewhat long post, but I'm going to be pasting every single piece of information relating to this issue and the method I am testing, from Controller class with method to the a.jax snippet. I have asked about 4-6 developers and no one can find out the reason why its giving me a 415 error instead of a 200, because it just seems like I am doing everything correct. I just need some fresh eyes and new perspectives, hopefully someone could help me solve this. I will be pasting the classes and the relevant pieces now, and then a couple comments after the snippets.

`Controller class`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class Controller
{

    @Autowired
    private Service service;
    
    public Controller() {
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/landing/{age}/{name}/{title}/{family}/{gender}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public @ResponseBody String update(@RequestBody HouseModel model, @PathVariable int age, @PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String title, @PathVariable String family, @PathVariable String gender)

    {
        String result = service.update(model, age, name, title, family, gender);
        
        // this will just return the string "Success" if update works or "Failed" if query is 
           wrong or not found

        return result;
    }
```

`Service Class`

```
@Service
public class Service
{
    @Autowired
    Dao dao;

    public Service() {
        
    }
    
    public String update(HouseModel model, int age, String name, String title, String family) 
    {
        return dao.update(HouseModel model, int age, String name, String title, String family);
    }

}
```

`Dao class`

```
@Repository
public class Dao
{   
    public Dao () {
        
    }
    
    public String update(HouseModel model, int age, String name, String title, String family) 
    {
    String result = "";
    //some long query that updates the table and will populate result as "Success" or "Failed"
    
    return result
    }
}
```

`Controller test class`

```
@EnableWebMvc
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext-testing.xml",
                                    "classpath:applicationContext-EIPW.xml"})
public class ControllerTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private Controller controller;
    
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

@Test
    public void test_update() throws Exception {
        
        String URI = "/user/landing/22/Test/Mr/Yes/Male";
        
        String content = "{\n    \"HouseId\": 5,\n    \"DateOfPurchase\": \"2019-01-01\",\n    \"Price\": 100,\n    \"Floors\": 5,\n    \"Style\": \"Victorian\",\n}";
         
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.put(URI).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(content).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print()).andReturn();
                
        
    }
```

`j.ajax`

```
$j.ajax({
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      type: "PUT",
      async: false,
      data: JSON.stringify(
        buildEdit(editRecords[i], ecRecord)
      ),
      url:
        "/user/landing/22/Test/Mr/Yes/Male",
      dataType: "text"
```

`printed error message`

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = PUT
         Request URI = /user/landing/22/Test/Mr/Yes/Male
          Parameters = {}
             Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=[application/json]}

             Handler:
                Type = controller.Controller

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 415
       Error message = null
             Headers = {Accept=[application/octet-stream, */*, text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1, */*, application/xml, text/xml, application/*+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data]}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

**Some Comments:**
So I've had over 50 stack overflow tabs open relating to the same problem, and a lot of them had similar solutions that seemed so simple. Here are some, if not all of the things I did in attempts to try and solve this problem:

1. Switched around the content-type and accepts headers of requestBuilder to be MediaTypes of APPLICATION_JSON or APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE or ALL_VALUE, etc
2. Added produces or consumes = "application/json" or MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON/APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE/ALL_VALUE into the requestMapping().
3. Played around with a.jax to change content-type or accepts around
4. A couple of other things that I don't remember, but alas the 415 status is still here

I also do have setters and a default constructor in the HouseModel, and default constructors in every layer. I am 99.9% sure I have tried almost everything, if not everything, unless I am just missing something and am being stupid then yeah. I sent the request with the body as JSON raw an as:

```
{
    "HouseId": 5,
    "DateOfPurchase": "2019-01-01",
    "Price": 100,
    "Floors": 5,
    "Style": "Victorian",
}
```

and it returned back success, I will attach its headers here:

[![Picture Link][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqKnY.png

There is something interesting though, I did get one method to work but it required no arguments in its parameters, it was just a get method (dao calls database to store stuff in a list):

```
**Controller method**

@RequestMapping(value = "/levels", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String getLevels() throws Exception
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // there is a long logic after this map to populate the map
        Map<LevelObject, List<LevelObject>> map = new HashMap<LevelObject, List<LevelObject>>();

        return mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
    }
```

This is such a simple test and it worked perfectly fine, giving me a status 200 and my expected result.

```
**Test class method**

@Test
    public void test_getLevels() throws Exception {
    
        String URI = "/user/levels";
                
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URI).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
                
        
    }
```

```
**j.ajax for the getLevels method**

$j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "user/levels",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: maybe some problems with @pathvariables and put method ? Why don't you try your method without path vars (as you did for  the /levels uri) ?

Comment: dataType: "text" - Your ajax call shouldn't be `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Never use the MockMvc "setup" methods if you're using Spring Boot; instead, use `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` and `@Autowired MockMvc`. (The "setup" methods make it _extremely_ easy to set up a test context that differs from your real environment enough to make your tests inaccurate.)

Comment: what do you mean my ajax call shouldn’t be dataType:json? I don’t think it is?

Comment: So, i dont need web application context setup?

Comment: You've shared the code snippet of $j.ajax call PUT request? Do you agree? Over there, the dataType was mentioned as "text" - Do you see it? Is that accurate? It should be "json"?

Comment: I tried changing it just now to json, but it still gave exact error message stack

Comment: Don't convert the json to String like `JSON.stringify` on the exact same $j.ajax PUT call and have a try? Please make sure you set the dataType as "json"

Comment: sorry @IHaveAQuestion i m very confused for your question have you solved? it is not so clear for me what is your issue? I mean java test and js are not related js is related for your production code test use a testable context with servlet mock can you please explain better your question?

Comment: @ValerioVaudi no, i have not solved it, it is still giving me the 415 error :/

Comment: But only on test side or Also with applicativo up and running?

Comment: only on the test side, postman works as intended for the method

Comment: I think its because when i am not setting contentType as MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE. I tried setting it but it says that contentType(MediaType) doesn't support strings

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not a front-end developer, I am sure that problem is in below line

```
data: JSON.stringify(
        buildEdit(editRecords[i], ecRecord)
      )
```

Reason - I tested your code locally. Code works fine from postman, if I select request body as raw and type as JSON
[image]

But if select request body as raw and type as "TXT". I am getting same error as you.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

So, I am sure that your request body is not being built as JSON. rather it is being sent as some other format. Hence, the error.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqSCC.png
Also, you can try to change dataType: "text" to dataType: "json"

Comment: Yeah. i changed text to json and it still gave the same error. But for your point, am I sending my String content correctly? I copy and pasted the body from postman to a online escape converter and copy and pasted the escaped json.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below,

```
$j.ajax({
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          type: "PUT",
          async: false,
          data:
            buildEdit(editRecords[i], ecRecord),
          url:
            "/user/landing/22/Test/Mr/Yes/Male",
          dataType: "json"
```

1. Remove converting the json to String
2. Change the dataType to json

Comment: So I tried this, and when I went onto the UI (website) and updated records, it said it failed with a 400 status. Is there a way to do this keeping the stringify AND text datatype there?

Comment: Yes, when your backend's return type is String then it's definitely should be "text".     dataType - The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

Comment: Im ignoring the actual UI right now, but I removed the stringify, and im still getting 415 error when i run the test

Comment: is there a concern for MockHttpResponse header where it says:


{Accept=[application/octet-stream, */*, text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1, */*, application/xml, text/xml, application/*+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data]}

Comment: When you're just returning the String as response say "Success" or "Failed" then you must use `produces = "text/plain"` Instead of json in your controller

Comment: I just tried that, same error still. I'm pretty sure ive tried a combination of produce and comsume both = text or MediaType.ALL